# How to upload WADL file with ".xml" extension in Soap UI Pro

Tags: soapui, wadl

I have an WADL file but with ".xml" extension.I need to use this file for testing purpose in Soap UI NG Pro tool.Soap UI Pro tool is not accepting a file with ".xml" extension. Please suggest how to test the REST services in the file or please suggest a way to save the file with ".wadl" extension so that I can import the file.

Comment: Try renaming it and importing it into soapui and see.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but no luck.

Comment: May be you should with your team if it is an internally developed? could be a possible defect as well. You can request for `wadl` only instead of xml.

Comment: Yes it is internally developed application. Will get in touch with our team as well.Thank You.

Comment: @Rao I had an .xml file, changed extension to .wadl and it worked!